# Java Xml Unmarshing typecast

Tags: java, xml, casting, unmarshalling

I am using JAXB to unmarsh xml files, which might contain different types, then the according classes. Here is a Range class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "range")
public class Range {

    @XmlAttribute
    private float   min;
    @XmlAttribute
    private float   max;

    public float getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(float min) {
        this.min = min;
    }


    public float getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(float max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

}
```

and the according xml text

```
<range min="0" max="width"/>
```

So as you see, the max value is not a float but a String. My program or the unmarshaller should be able to deal with that, maybe by calling another setter method like below. Is something like this possible.

```
public void setMax(String max) {
    this.max = Constants.getValueOf(max);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you run this? It should have worked. Otherwise, yes, you can annotate your setters instead of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `field` from `float` to `Float` you can write an `XmlAdapter` to handle this use case.

```
public class MyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Float> {
    // Your logic for converting between the String and Float
}
```

Then you can reference the `XmlAdapter` using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation:

```
@XmlAttribute
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyAdapter.class)
private Float   max;
```